# Want to add popup entry in Allow popup option of firefox using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, htmlunit

I want to add popup blocker entry for the specific site in htmlunit webclient

we can do it manually by clicking to edit popup blocker entry option in browser but how

to do it in htmlunit

is it possible ?

if yes ......how?

I want to do this in htmlunit

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ofcourse this has to be done manual, that's the whole point. The user controls the browser, not you. Why not use a lightbox with text support or something?